# Aviso de notificaciones en laravel

Tags: php, javascript, html, laravel

Me gustaria desarrollar, un sistema de avisos con el que pueda saber cuantas solicitudes hay pendientes de tramitar, en este caso, quiero hacer esto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

(Ya se que el estilo no esta muy alla, no es prioritario ahora)

Código:

```
<span id="notifications" class="tag tag tag-primary tag-pill float-xs-right mr-2">5</span>
<script type= text/javascript>

    var notice = <?= $data ?>;
    console.log(notice)

    $.ajax({
        url: notifications
    }).done(function(data) {
        console.log(data);
        var response = $.parseJSON(data);
        console.log(response);
            $document.getElementById(“notifications).value = "response"; 

        });
</script>
```

Como pueden ver la notificación es de bootstrap, y el numero simplemente esta escrito a mano.

He escrito este método en el controlador, que simplemente hace la consulta y devuelve los datos:

```
public function alertas()
{
    $data = \DB::table('vacations')->select('*')->count();
    print_r($data);
    return $data;
}
```

web.php:

```
 Route::get('/notifications', 'VacationController@alertas');
```

Mi problema esta en que;

1 - Aunque tenga definida la url o ruta en el archivo web.php no me coge la ruta el ajax.

2 - La otra manera que intente ha sido pasándole directamente los datos como parámetro al cargar la vista:

```
public function index()
{
    $notifications = $this->alertas();
    return view('home')->with('notifications',$notifications);   
}
```

Pero claro, tendría que duplicar esto para todos los controladores para que me cargue las notificaciones correctamente, ya que donde quiero mostrar las notificaciones es en el layout padre, y la verdad me ha dejado un poco dudoso, ya que no le envio datos al layout principal nunca, solo a los hijos que son los que cargan al padre, si no me equivoco claro...

He estado viendo que existe el metodo View::share, pero no me termina de funcionar ya que no obtengo los datos en la vista.

Edito:

He conseguido enviar los datos a través del AppServiceProvider, pero a la hora de implementar mi método en el boot me descuadra el estilo de las vistas.

El código que use en el AppServiceProvider es este:

```
View::composer('*', function($view){
        $view->with('data', $this->alertas());
});
```

He probado con el `View::share` tambien, pero no logra pasarle la variable.

Edito2: Aplicando el middleware como me propusieron he añadido en kernel el middleware, y he dejado el metodo del middleware asi:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    $data = \DB::table('vacations')->select('*')->count();
    view()->share(compact('data'));
    return $next($request);
}
```

ruta:

```
    Route::get('/notifications', 'CalendarController@alertas')->middleware('notif');
```

Metodo alertas()

```
public function alertas()
{
    $data = \DB::table('vacations')->select('*')->where(['vacations.aceptado' => '0'])->count();
    return $data;
}
```

y me devuelve este error:

```
Undefined variable: data (View: /var/www/html/sistemalaravel/resources/views/layouts/app.blade.php) (View: /var/www/html/sistemalaravel/resources/views/layouts/app.blade.php)
```

No se que puedo estar haciendo mal, por lo que entiendo no esta llegando el parámetro del middleware a la vista padre. La ruta debe apuntar al middleware o algo así? Gracias.

Comment: ¿Puedes enseñarnos como defines la ruta en web.php y la ruta a la que envias la petición desde AJAX?

Comment: @FranciscoGarrido he editado el post con la ruta de web.php, y el ajax lo tienes en el codigo del javascript, simplemente llamo a la ruta notifications, me gustaría saber que problema hay, aunque creo que esa manera no me va a servir.

Comment: ¿No estas asignando una variable en `url: notifications`? Ahora mismo no estoy seguro, por eso te pregunte por la ruta que llamabas. ¿No seria `url: '/notifications'`?

Comment: Igual lo que me faltan son las comillas, pero lo de la barra si no me equivoco creo que es opcional ya que la ruta la estableci yo, se la pondre para probar

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para hacer notificaciones lo ideal sería usar `WebSockets` para poder recibir los datos en tiempo real, Laravel ya viene con soporte de 2 drivers, `Pusher` y `Redis`, recomendaría usar `redis`ya que `pusher` es de paga, para esto también necesitarás instalar `NodeJS` y normalmente vas a ocupar un servidor dedicado ya que en los compartidos casi nunca te dan permisos para poder instalar librerías tales como `Node`.

Ahora que si quieres que se muestren las notificaciones aunque se tenga que recargar la página podrías crear un middleware y aplicarlo a las rutas que ocuparán esa variable de notificación.

**1. Crear Middleware**

En tu terminal ejecuta el comando

`php artisan make:middleware NotificacionesMiddleware`

**2. Registra el Middleware creado en tu App\Http\Kernel.php**

En el array llamado `$routeMiddleware` agrégale un alias al middleware con el que lo usarás en las rutas y especifícale la ruta:

```
'notif' => \App\Http\Middleware\NotificacionesMiddleware::class,
```

**3. Escribe el código que obtendrá las notificaciones**

Dentro de tu middleware recién creado comparte con las vistas las variables que deseas usar:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next){
   $num_notificaciones = 4;
   $otra_notificacion = 'Nuevo Mensaje';

   view()->share(compact('num_notificaciones', 'otra_notificacion'));
   return $next($request);
}
```

**4. Aplica el middleware a la ruta, rutas o grupo de rutas que lo usarán**

Una vez que ya tienes la lógica que te devolverán el número de notificaciones, debes de asignar el middleware a las rutas que te desplegarán las vistas que usarán esas variables.

Puedes hacerlo de una en una:

```
Route::get('/admin', 'Controlador@index')->name('prueba')->middleware('notif');
```

De esta forma, la o las vistas que ocupe, en este caso, el método `index` del controlador estarán disponibles.

O también, puedes aplicar el middleware a un grupo de rutas:

```
Route::middleware('notif')->group(function () {
   Route::get('/admin', 'Controlador@index')->name('prueba');
});
```

En ese caso, cualquier ruta dentro de ese grupo de rutas aplicará el middleware ya explicado y podrán usar las variables que está compartiendo.

Comment: Muchas gracias @Aarón Gutiérrez, voy a probarlo ahora mismo y te digo algo.

Comment: He probado a añadir el middleware y me tira error de MethodNotAllowedHttp, quiero preguntarte, si tengo que modificar algo en el metodo de alertas, porque realmente el $num_notifications que le tengo que pasar al view->share es una consulta a la DB, edito el post, pero he hecho basicamente lo que me has propuesto solo cambiando el metodo del middleware por el mio

Comment: @Peisou Ese error es cuando tratas de acceder por un método equivocado a la ruta, es decir, por ejemplo, que tengas la ruta registrada como `GET` y trates de acceder con `POST`. Verifica que esté bien el código que he escrito y lo apliques en tu proyecto.

Comment: He editado el post, con el fallo que tengo, creo que el metodo no me lo coje bien, ya que ahora solo me dice que la variable no esta definida.

Comment: @Peisou ¿Puedes agregar tu método `alertas` de tu controlador `CalendarController`?

Comment: es el mismo que el handle del middleware, son 2 lineas de codigo, la consulta y devolver la $data simplemente

Comment: @Peisou De cualquier forma, ¿lo puedes poner?, ese método de ese controlador debe de devolver la vista, no tiene que devolver la variable nuevamente...

Comment: he editado el post con el metodo, pero vamos que realmente me da igual omitir el metodo como te decia es un select y retornar valor.

Comment: @Peisou Ya, no es correcto lo que haces, si tu variable `$data` contiene lo mismo que `$data` en el `middleware` no tienes que volver a consultarla, por tanto, si no tienes nada extra que hacer en el método `alertas()` sólo regresa la vista:

`public function alertas()
{
    return view('tu-vista');
} `

Lo que hace el middleware es que a todas las vistas que usen tus métodos a los que aplique el middleware, les hará saber que la variable `$data` está presente, por lo tanto si pones `return $data`, las vistas que uses no sabrán que existe la variable.

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/90726/discussion-between-peisou-and-aaron-gutierrez).

Comment: Funciona a la perfección tras aclarar un fallo de uso con @Aarón Gutiérrez Muchas gracias!!

Answer (score 2):

Dale un formato a tu respuesta. Yo tengo algo similar y lo utilizo de esta

manera en la controladora: `return response()->json($data).`

web: `Route::get('/getNotificaciones', 'HomeController@getNotificaciones');`

En ajax:

```
url: "/getNotificaciones",
         type: 'get'
```